# How to associate node with products in Drupal/Ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I am looking for a way to allow users to add node reference to each product or whole cart @ checkout. I am making web site where users can buy items and then receive them on board flight. Products are fixed, but user needs to tell for which flight he is buying items. Flights are nodes and users has flagged these nodes so there is no problem making View with users flagged flight nodes. How would I associate one of these nodes with purchase? Nodereference from CCK would be cool, but checkout is probably not node.

Any suggestions for approach?

Answer (score 1):

The Node Checkout module might do the trick for you, though it sounds like you might be looking to do more than one product at a time, but it might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with Tim. You can associate flight & items in a node. This node will be associated to a product using node checkout.
I have used node checkout in my [site](http://www.utilitiesindia.com) for example in send letter online under send information.
Checkout this : http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/03/event-registration-ubercart

http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/03/event-registration-ubercart